# Can't get onItemClickListener to work

Tags: android

I've tried various solutions on SO, none solved my problem. The toast just doesn't show, neither does the `Log.d` entry... Here's my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_row, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            String text = "Clicked " + Integer.toString(position) + ":" + Long.toString(id);
            toast.setText(text);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            Log.d("BagIt.ItemClick", text);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Are you set listener to the correct listview?

Comment: Yep, it's the only listview I have...

Comment: I suggest you move the setOnItemClickListener() call to onActivityCreated() override.

Comment: do you have item in your listView, post the adapter if you have it

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it threw a java.lang.RuntimeException because Toast was not created with Toast.makeText(). 
Try this instead.

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = "Clicked " + position + ":" + id;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still though, I had no exception, and the Log.d didn't work anyway, so the code wasn't executing in the first place.

Comment: OK please post your adapter code and how you added items to your listview

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I noticed that your list view has nothing in it.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_row, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //set your array adapter here to your list view and pass the array of items

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        String text = "Clicked " + Integer.toString(position) + ":" + Long.toString(id);
        toast.setText(text);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        Log.d("BagIt.ItemClick", text);
       }
   });
   return v;
}
```

You might want to add some items to your list view first then attempt to click them. Otherwise you will have an empty list view.

I would use an array adapter or the appropriate adapter depending on the type of data you want to show on your list view.

Comment: So I was following a combination of articles that did something a bit weird but eventually, loaded fragments into the `ListView` with an adapter. So it does have items in it, but maybe not the way I'm expecting? The items are loaded through `onCreate` in an `AsyncTask`, could that bet the problem?

Comment: The way it is normally done is you set the adapter on the list view then pass a list of items to it. I don't know how that tutorial works; a link would help. So once you get a reference to your list view, you then set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your adapter code and your listview item layout?

It's possible there is some item in your list view (like a checkbox) that is grabbing focus rather than the entire row layout.

Also, your code doesn't show your listview adapter being created or even set to the listview to actually populate.

If you could post those classes, we might be able to be of more help